# can not open the drop-down arrow besides the report in SSRS report manager to add subscription

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, reportmanager

I try to configure the report manager. It is sql2008r2 report service running on server 2013. There is no problem to pull the report. But I can not open the drop-down arrow besides the report to add subscription.

I add the virtual directory, reports, with C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager in physical path under default web site.

does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 52):

Try adding your report server URL to your list of compatibility view sites. I experienced the same issue on our 2008 report server.

Comment: The drop-down menus would not load on our SSRS 2008 R2 report manager. Adding the server to the compatibility view sites immediately fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: http://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/add-sites-to-internet-explorer-8-ie-8-compatibility-view

Comment: Obviously a native Microsoft browser-required product is not going to be compatible with Microsoft's only web browser Internet Explorer.How is this not obvious to you all?  (actually this all relates to a 6.0 bug that MSFT exploits to render Chrome and Mozilla useless. This kind of practice HAS TO STOP!)

Answer (score 9):

This drop-down issue is an issue with the compatibility setting. Go to: Tools/Compatibility View Settings and enter "localhost" and/or whatever your  is (do both). "Fixes" things up. BUT, since there's two issues here, do note that you'll still need to open IE as "run as admin".

Answer (score 3):

Go to right corner in internet explorer
Then choose the Page icon.
check  compatibility view

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, changing the localhost into the machine name solved it for me too. But only in Internet Explorer. In Firefox and other browser the dropdown still won't pop up. But there are more configuration-issues with the combination ReportServer <-> not IE browsers.

Comment: This should be a comment. This is not an answer to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This is now a very old topic but in case someone like me still struggles now that IE is reaching end of life.
What I did was I took the URL now from IE while I still had that working so I can use the same format in Edge and Chrome to access the options by manually altering the url.

"report server url"/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/"report folder name"/"report name"&SelectedTabId=PropertiesTab

e.g.
https://example.com/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/myreportfolder/myreport&SelectedTabId=PropertiesTab

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such server as server 2013 - but I doubt that's particularly important. The 2 endpoints deployed by SSRS 2008 R2 are localhost/ReportServer and localhost/Reports - reports is the Report Manager endpoint, although I suppose you could rename it in the configuration manager. There is NO setup in IIS for these endpoints - SSRS takes care of that directly, so there's no node for either endpoint in IIS to configure.

I am looking at my install of ReportManager, and I don't see any "tabs" for Contents or Properties - why do you think they should exist?

I know we're not supposed to seek clarification of questions, but I don't know how to answer your question as asked.

Comment: Eric, Report manager 2005 has those two tabs. So how you enter subscription on report manager 2008?

Comment: OK - just re-read your original question and realize this is where you're having the problem. Unfortunately, I haven't run into the situation where I couldn't open the menu as follows: Navigate to the report, click the down-arrow on the right side of the report, and pick Subscribe -  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/472206/ssrssubscribe.png

Comment: Here is the update. I can open the drop-down box on other computers But not on the report Server. Someone has same experience?

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing this issue. This was because of some authentication issue. I was trying to open the report manager on my local system with the url (http:// localhost/reports) but the dropdown was not coming to view, delete ,subscribe the reports on clicking the report. I tried opening the internet explorer in admin mode also and still there was the same issue. Then i changed the url i was opening to http:// machine name/reports and the dropdown menu started displaying.
Instead of localhost, try opening the report manager by the machine name and it should work.
Also you must have the rights to access the report server(For that open IE in admin mode and go to Report manager->site settings and assign a role to the user.)

Answer (score 0):

You can click on report, then check the very top of the *Internet Explorer* page (the place that shows Home in hyperlink), then you would see the path of your report + your report name in hyperlink.

- Click on your report name which is hyperlink and then it will open
  the manage page which includes subscriptions.
- Click on the subscription and now you can have your new subscription
  added.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using IE Edge and the easiest solution was once I had my list of reports in IE Edge, was to click the elipses (...) at the top right-hand corner and then choose Open with Internet Explorer.